# Prove for every number $c$ such that $c \geq f(y)$, there is $x \in (a,b)$ such that $f(x) = c$ - Proof Verification

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, continuity

Let $f:(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $(a,b)$. Assume that $\lim_{x \to a^{+}}f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to b^{-}}f(x) = \infty$. Let $y \in (a,b)$ such that $f$ attains its minimum. Prove that for every number $c$ such that $c \geq f(y)$, there is $x \in (a,b)$ such that $f(x) = c$

**Attempt:**

We are given that $\lim_{x \to a^{+}}f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to b^{-}}f(x) = \infty$. By definition this means that for every $M(\text{or}\ N) > 0$, there exists a $\delta_{M}(\text{or}\ \delta_{N}) > 0$ such that if $0< x-a < \delta_{M} \ (0 < b-x < \delta_{N})$ that $f(x) > M(\text{or}\ N)$. We also know that $f(y)$ is the minimum. This would mean we can let $M = N = f(y)$. As such we know that the $\delta$ we choose will be satisfactory. Let $\delta = b-a$.

Therefore we have $$0 < x-a < b-a \\\Rightarrow a < x < b$$

The same manipulation can be performed for $0 < b - x < b-a$.

In both cases we have illustrated an $x \in (a,b)$. Now by continuity this means $f(x) = c$.

Is this the right approach.

**Comment:** When I first read the claim the conditions are very similar to those to be able to apply the Intermediate Value Theorem, except we have an open interval $(a,b)$ instead of the required closed interval. I was trying to brainstorm a way to make the interval "closed" so then I could apply IVT, but didn't come up with anything concrete. Perhaps there is a meaning behind divergence I may be missing.

Comment: It is not clear when you said: by continuity this means ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

Let $ c\in \Bbb R $ such that $$c>f(y)$$

Define $ g $ at $ (a,b) $ by
$$g(x)=f(x)-c$$
at first observe that $$g(y)<0$$

On the other hand, there exists $ u \in (a,b) $ satisying
$$f(u)>c$$
because $\lim_{a^+}f=+\infty$ (with $M=c)$

thus $$g(u)>0$$

Now, apply IVT at $ [u,y] $.

Comment: Two things: 1) In conclusion this technique works because we $y$ could be anywhere on the interval right? 2) What motivated you to define $g(x) = f(x) - c$? What made you comfortable defining another function in this way?

Comment: @dc3rd the idea comes from the fact that $f(x)=c$ can be written as $ f(x)-c=0$ to use IVT.